# Can I write OpenGL ES2 code for android in kotlin without android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I need to write a small opengl ES 2 application for android 8+, but I just want to write a proof of concept with kotlin before deploying it on a phone.

Are there code samples for the specifics of OpenGL ES2 on android and GLsurface?

Is it possible to not use android studio on windows since it's pretty heavy to use on a small laptop?

Comment: You can look at the source code of [libGDX](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx) to see how they work with the GL surface and made it platform-agnostic so you can test it on a PC without building for Android at all. I think trying to write something in Kotlin without IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio would probably be quite painful, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basics:

[Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl#basics)

[Basic setup](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment)

You're effectively setting up your `GlSurface` and giving it a `Renderer` that you've created, which has a few callbacks where you do setup (e.g. `onSurfaceChanged`) and drawing (`onDrawFrame`, which gets called every frame in a loop). That's where you do your standard OpenGL ES calls, so if you're writing some generic Kotlin code, you could call it from these.

Android also creates a renderer thread for you, and all your `Renderer` calls happen on that thread (and it also has the OpenGL context), so that's something to keep in mind if you want to communicate with it.